# how to store a huge string (length 50000) in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

how to store a huge string (length 50000) in mysql using python.
I have a big string of length nearly 50000 .I have to store it into mysql.
Some suggested to store the string as a blob or text type.

Can anyone help me how to convert string into blob type

```
def main():
    stringKey=''
    stringValues=''
    keys=ccv.keys()        //ccv is a dictionary data structure  
    vectors=ccv.values()  //ccv is a dictionary data structure 
    for key in keys:
            stringKey='#'.join(key for key in keys)
    for value in vectors:
            stringValues='$'.join(str(value) for value in vectors)
    insert(stringKey,stringValues)
    print 'insert successful'

def insert(k,v):
    db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='abhi',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='cbir')

    sql= 'INSERT INTO ccv(key,vector) VALUES(%s,%s)'
    args = (k,v)
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql,args)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

error:

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key,vector) VALUES('27:1:8#27:1:9#25:2:11#6:9:8#6:9:9#6:9:6#6:9:7#6:9:4#6:9:5#27' at line 1
```

Comment: Is it perhaps an option to store the data in a file and merely save a path to the file in the database? Storing over 50KB for a single record seems a bit overkill for a RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small error in:

```
'INSERT INTO ccv(key,vector) VALUES(%s,%s)'
```

It should be:

```
"INSERT INTO ccv (`key`, `vector`) VALUES(%s, %s)"
```

Notice the `` ` `` denoting the column names.

As Larry reminded me the values don't have to be quoted for parameterized queries.

If the fields are already set for longtext this should work without needing to convert the data to blobs.

The problem was only related to the syntax and not the data or column types.

Comment: ID quoting is not required unless there are otherwise invalid characters in the column name, and string quoting is not required for a parameterized SQL statement.

Comment: I just tested the command using the mysql client and ID quoting solved the problem OP was having. As for the quoting be optional that's something I forgot. Let me fix that.

Comment: Looking again, you'll probably need to id quote the work `key`, but `vector` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the string, you need to change the field type in your database from varchar to longtext.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your code. Please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: table ccv contains two columns key and vector both of type longtext

Answer (score 0):

You are not associating the arguments with the SQL statement.

You want

```
 cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

instead of

```
 cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: The word `key` is probably a reserved word in MySQL.  You should ID quote that column name.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to do with that INSERT statement?  Your loops are a little confused, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "INSERT INTO ccv(`key`,`vector`) VALUES(%s,%s)"
```

this works fine